# Why does `cat` seem to iterate over JSON arrays?

Tags: bash, cat, fifo, here-document, json

I'm puzzled by this behaviour of `cat` when trying to output a heredoc containing JSON in bash 3.2:

input:

```
$ cat <(cat <<EOF
> {"x":[{"a":1,"b":2}]}
> EOF)
```

output:

```
{"x":["a":1]}
{"x":["b":2]}
```

What's going on?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which version of bash?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Fedora 14 or 21 nor CentOS 6.6 what are you using?

Comment: Bash 3.2 - I will update the question

Comment: This "brace expansion" can be disabled with `set +B`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just shell variable expansion by bash.  In this context whatever is between the curly braces will be iterated and expanded into the expression.

```
$ echo var{1,2,3,4}
var1 var2 var3 var4

$ echo var{1..10}
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8 var9 var10
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a formatted comment:

```
$ cat <(cat <<EOF
> {"x":[{"a":1,"b":2}]}
> EOF)
bash: warning: here-document at line 15 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
bash: warning: here-document at line 15 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
{"x":[{"a":1,"b":2}]}
```

Put the closing parenthesis on a new line

```
$ cat <(cat <<EOF
> {"x":[{"a":1,"b":2}]}
> EOF
> )
{"x":[{"a":1,"b":2}]}
```

and clearly, I can't reproduce:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.3.39(1)-release
```

Answer (score 0):

Brace expansion is subject to the "braceexpand" option. For example:

```
set +B
cat <(cat <<EOF
{"x":[{"a":1,"b":2}]}
EOF
)
```

produces the single JSON value.